# Emulator is not launching

Tags: android

Getting warning when i am launching emulator please help me

```
Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
```

Comment: Goto DDMS perspective, click on the down arrow next to the screen capture camera icon and select reset adb from the dropdown menu.

Comment: go to cmd to \android-sdk\platform-tools dir and type adb kill-server and then adb start-server or restart your eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows open command prompt (cmd.exe). In Linux open Terminal. Locate adb.exe in SDK folder

```
..\android-sdk\platform-tools\abd.exe
cd <sdk directory> (move to the folder listed above)
dir (to make sure abd.exe is in that directory)
adb kill-server (stop the abd service, won't return anything)
adb start-server (start the abd service back up, should give a couple of readings)
```

Comment: there is no abd.exe in plateform-tools

Comment: This is not possible... By the way its platform-tools and adb.exe, there is typo mistake in your comment.

Comment: sorry for mistakes i got adb.exe in platform-tools now what i do

Comment: now open your terminal and go to platform-tools folder, and then fire these commands: adb kill-server (stop the abd service, won't return anything)
'adb start-server (start the abd service back up, should give a couple of readings)'

Comment: i did it ..now i am getting a message "emulator arm.exe has stopped working"

Answer (score 1):

delete that emulator and create another new emulator. Make sure that there is only 1 emulator in AVD SDK manager. try it, may it has solve your problem.

Comment: AVD can have multiple emulator

Comment: yes but sometimes due to multiple emulator throws the exception to launch the activity bcz the data or cache data are in used in another emul.

Comment: i have done it but there is no effect and AVD have only one emulator

Answer (score 0):

Try to emulate different model. E.g. in my case, I was using nexus 4 and an error occured everytime. After that I tried to change model (4.0", 1024 RAM) and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This warning means your data partition (userdata-qemu.img) and cache parition (cache.img) are being used. There may be other emulators running. 
Or, there might be some inconsistent state of your emulator images.

If you are sure there is no other emulators running, then delete the "file lock" in the avd directory. The dir should be ~/.android/avd/[NAME OF YOUR AVD]/. And the "file lock" should be userdata-qemu.img.lock and cache.img.lock.